# invalid SOAP request needs experienced eye

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, wsdl, savon

### TLDR: the solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50261599/182484)

I'm using [savon](http://savonrb.com/version2/globals.html) to make requests against a SOAP service.  I know... Gross.

Regardless, I'm having trouble making Savon behave.  The SOAP provider has [this](https://services.promostandards.org/webserviceValidator/home) validator, which takes the following inputs:

```
Web Service: ProductData
Version: 1.0.0
Operation: getProductSellable
Endpoint: https://psproductdata100-stg.pcna.online
```

When I use the validator, I enter this xml:

```
<GetProductSellableRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.promostandards.org/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/">
  <wsVersion xmlns="http://www.promostandards.org/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/SharedObjects/">1.0.0</wsVersion>
</GetProductSellableRequest>
```

And I get this response body

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetProductSellableResponse xmlns="http://www.promostandards.org/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/">
      <ErrorMessage xmlns="http://www.promostandards.org/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/SharedObjects/">
        <code>110</code>
        <description>Authentication Credentials Required</description>
      </ErrorMessage>
    </GetProductSellableResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

That response is valid because I did not provide my un/pw.  If I do provide credentials, I get a full response.  Below is a screenshot of that happening in my browser.

[image]

However, when I use Savon to make the same request

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'savon'
require 'awesome_print'
require 'byebug'
require 'pry'

endpoint = 'https://psproductdata100-stg.pcna.online'
path = 'psProductData.svc?singleWsdl'
wsdl = "#{endpoint}/#{path}"

args = {
  wsdl: wsdl,
  log: true,
  log_level: :debug,
  pretty_print_xml: true,
  element_form_default: :qualified
}

client = Savon.client(args) do
  convert_request_keys_to :lower_camelcase
end

message = { ws_version: '1.0.0' }
response = client.call(:get_product_sellable) do
  message(message)
end

ap response
```

The response does not come back as expected.  The XML looks *close* to what was sent by the validator, but not exact.

Heres the request

```
D, [2018-04-26T18:01:00.471662 #89854] DEBUG -- : HTTPI /peer GET request to psproductdata100-stg.pcna.online (net_http)
I, [2018-04-26T18:01:00.979809 #89854]  INFO -- : SOAP request: https://psproductdata100-stg.pcna.online/psProductData.svc
I, [2018-04-26T18:01:00.979886 #89854]  INFO -- : SOAPAction: "getProductSellable", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 501
D, [2018-04-26T18:01:00.980107 #89854] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://www.promostandards.org/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ins0="http://www.promostandards.org/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/SharedObjects/">
  <env:Body>
    <tns:GetProductSellableRequest>
      <tns:wsVersion>1.0.0</tns:wsVersion>
    </tns:GetProductSellableRequest>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

And the response

```
D, [2018-04-26T18:01:00.980224 #89854] DEBUG -- : HTTPI /peer POST request to psproductdata100-stg.pcna.online (net_http)
I, [2018-04-26T18:01:01.650449 #89854]  INFO -- : SOAP response (status 200)
D, [2018-04-26T18:01:01.650731 #89854] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetProductSellableResponse xmlns="http://www.promostandards.org/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/">
      <ErrorMessage xmlns="http://www.promostandards.org/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/SharedObjects/">
        <code>110</code>
        <description>Version mismatch.</description>
      </ErrorMessage>
    </GetProductSellableResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

and the output from Savon

```
{
    :get_product_sellable_response => {
        :error_message => {
                   :code => "110",
            :description => "Version mismatch.",
                 :@xmlns => "http://www.promostandards.org/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/SharedObjects/"
        },
               :@xmlns => "http://www.promostandards.org/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/"
    },
                     :"@xmlns:xsi" => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                     :"@xmlns:xsd" => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
}
```

Comment: Please remove "solved" from your title and move your solution to its own answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar problem with namespaces [ruby savon and wsdl namespacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331730/ruby-savon-and-wsdl-namespacing). I believe you have the same problem.

Additional Note: Try to use SOAP UI to debug, the generated XML from the WSDL and see the difference. Also change the XML to the XML generated from the code and validate the XML in SOAP UI. It will show the errors if any in SOAP UI, will make debugging faster and errors more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the other answers on this thread, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47349812/182484) post.  I read up on how namespaces work, as well as linked XSD files.  By combining my new knowledge with that post, I was a able to build out something like this:

```
require 'savon'
require 'awesome_print'
require 'byebug'
require 'pry'

endpoint = 'https://psproductdata100-stg.pcna.online'
path = 'psProductData.svc?singleWsdl'
wsdl = "#{endpoint}/#{path}"

args = {
  wsdl: wsdl,
  log: false,
  log_level: :debug,
  pretty_print_xml: true,
  element_form_default: :qualified
}

client = Savon.client(args) do
  convert_request_keys_to :lower_camelcase
  namespaces 'xmlns:shar' => 'http://www.promostandards.org/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/SharedObjects/'
end

message =  {
  'shar:wsVersion' => '1.0.0',
  'shar:id' => 'REDACTED',
  'shar:password' => 'REDACTED'

}
response = client.call(:get_product_sellable) do
  message(message)
end

ap response.body[:get_product_sellable_response][:product_sellable_array][:product_sellable][0..2]
```

Now i'm more fun to talk to at dinner parties.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is a namespace problem.  The wsVersion is within the shared object namespace "ins0".  It is not in the "tns" namespace.  Try changing your request to look like the following:

```
<env:Body>
  <tns:GetProductSellableRequest>
    <ins0:wsVersion>1.0.0</ins0:wsVersion>
  </tns:GetProductSellableRequest>
</env:Body>
```